# Sorting and keeping the main format of list numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, sorting

I have a list with these elements:

```
list={1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), 1, 1, 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 0};
```

[image]

I want to sort them with

```
Sort[list];
```

I see the bellow result:

[image]

Which is incorrect, because `N[1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])]= -0.6`, However I can write `Sort[N[list]]` but I need to have the exact numbers, not their approximate values (I mean that I need `1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])` instead of `-0.6`).

Comment: This seems like a bug, possibly related to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95056/simple-arithmetic-with-irrationals-fails#comment257149_95056). In any case, you can use `Sort[list,N]` to apply `N` before sorting (but keeping the original exact values).

Comment: But it doesn't work: Sort[list, N, Less], because it has to be from Smaller to Larger, also, the command line is associated with a massage that I could not understand that's mean.

Comment: This is a really weird behavior. I'm pretty sure it's a bug, and should be reported to Wolfram. In any case, you can solve your problem with `Sort[list, N[#1] < N[#2] &]`

Comment: @yohbs, mr.0093 This is actually NOT a bug: this behavior may be counter-intuitive, but it is well described in the `Sort` documentation. This is also mentioned in the pitfalls FAQ: [Using `Sort` incorrectly](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78183/27951).

Comment: @mr.0093 Of course `Ordering[]` works. The point of `Ordering[]` is that your create a list of "sort keys" that `Sort[]` and `Odering[]` can deal with, and you sort _that_ instead of your original list. `Ordering[]` will thus tell you in which sequence you should pick the elements of the original list to get the same sequence as the auxiliary list after sorting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the Possible Issues section of the documentation for [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html): "Numeric expressions are sorted by structure as well as numerical value"

```
list = {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), 1, 1, 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 0};
```

The approach recommended there to `Sort` by numerical value only is

```
sorted = Sort[list, Less]

(*  {(1/2)*(1 - Sqrt[5]), 0, 1, 1, 
   (1/2)*(1 + Sqrt[5])}  *)
```

Verifying numeric order

```
% // N

(*  {-0.618034, 0., 1., 1., 1.61803}  *)
```

Or equivalently,

```
sorted === Sort[list, #1 < #2 &]

(*  True  *)
```

Or use [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html)

```
sorted === SortBy[list, N]

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Not a bug. The docs: "Sort usually orders expressions by putting shorter ones first, and then comparing parts in a depth‐first manner."

You want `SortBy[list,N]`, I think. For more complex cases, use `Ordering[]` to get a list of indexes and use that to reorder the original list:

```
Ordering@N@list
list[[%]]
```

---

Perhaps you should consider the option of handing `Sort[]` your own ordering predicate. Just use any pure function whatsoever which works on `#1` and `#2` and returns True if `#1` comes before `#2` in your desired sort order, or False otherwise:

```
peopleAndAges={{"Felix",50},{"Max",19},{"Sophie",22}};
CompareByName[{n1_String,_},{n2_String}]:=(ToLowerCase@n1 <= ToLowerCase@n2)
CompareByAge[{_,a1_},{_,a2_}]:=(a1 >= a2)

Sort[peopleAndAges,CompareByAge]
```